# Скрипт автоматического F5, с указанными промежутками времени

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

```
<script>
function subm() {
document.forms['form1'].submit();
}
setTimeout(subm, 1);
</script>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<label>
<input type="hidden" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
</label>
<label>
<input type="button" name="go" id="go" value="" onclick="subm()" />
</label>
</form>
```

Этот код при добавлении на страницу делает ей обновление (F5) по указанному промежутку времени. setTimeout(subm, 1); - означает 1/1000 секунды. Собственно код устраивает. Можно ли каким-то образом, чтобы функция обновления висела не на форме? (В идеале, чтобы просто был скрипт, с указанием в нем времени).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно наверное как-то так:

```
<script>
function reloadPage(timeToReloadAfter)
{
   setTimeout("location.reload();",time);
}
</script>
...
<body onload="reloadPage(1000)">
...
</body>
```

Comment: уберите кавычки, `eval` здесь вообще не нужен

Comment: обоснуйте?

Comment: я ответу рад, но что же вы в субботу не отдыхаете блин? 8-)

Comment: > обоснуйте?
что именно!

;-)

Comment: Почему надо убрать кавычки, и почему не нужен eval (точнее даже почему его нельзя использовать) ?

Comment: Вызов `setTimeout` со строковым аргументом суть `eval`, а, как известно, [**`eval` is evil**](http://xkr.us/js/eval).

В данном конкретном случае эквивалентного поведения при чистом коде можно добиться, просто убрав пунктуацию.

> почему его нельзя использовать

В принципе, эта тема достойна отдельного вопроса.

Comment: просто кавычки убрать - думаю нужного эффекта не будет  надо именно знаки все порешать :- ) setTimeout(location.reload,time);

Comment: Да, всю пунктуацию. Я бы снял минус, если бы вы отредактировали ответ...